# Magento 2.0.7 Cart Price Rule - spend £30, get one free item for free

Tags: magento

Getting quite frustrated with Magento 2's cart price rules today! We want to launch new offer on our shop:

- Spend £30+ and receive a free tshirt (either SKU a or SKU b)

We've tried using the standard vanilla Buy X Get Y Free rule, but simply cannot get the rule to work.

The Conditions look like this:

[Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6bto.jpg)

And the Actions look like this:

[Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRN2v.jpg)

Any help would be very much appreciated. I am concerned that what we are trying to achieve might not be possible with the Magento 2 vanilla cart price rules logic.

Thanks!

Comment: Ask here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?